# Does brake bleeding order matter on vehicles with ABS and stability control?

Tags: brakes, electronic-stability-control

A few of my cars have four-line brake systems with ABS and stability control.

Does the order in which the brakes are bled really matter? The lines appear to be entirely independent downstream of the brake controller in the engine bay.

(Yes, I've seen [this thread](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/27998/does-the-brake-bleeding-sequence-really-matter) and others, but none, as far as I can tell, address a four-line system.)

I could imagine this being important on a three-line system, but on any car where the computers can actuate all four of the brakes independently, I can't see how it would matter.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does matter.

When trying to push small air bubbles out of the abs block the internal paths effectively define the order necessary for bleeding.

So follow the manufacturers instructions...

The order for my Jag X type is Right rear, left rear, front right, front left (left and right defined when standing at the front of the car facing it...) and it does have abs...